# prime divisibility:v what is the formula?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

I know how to divide certain numbers, like $$\frac{x}{2}$$ whereas $x$ ends in 2, 4, 6, 8, or 0. and my idea to represent $x$ is $$a+10b+100c+1000d...$$ and it is divisible by 3 if $$\frac{a+b+c+d...}{3}$$ is a whole number.

$\frac{x}{5}$ is possible if the number ends in 0 or 5.

$\frac{x}{6}$ is possible if $\frac {x}{3}$ and $\frac{x}{2}$ are both possible. this is the same for all composite numbers.

my big question is: what about larger $$\frac{x}{p}$$ where p is any prime number and x is any number you are trying to test? is there any formula that can be directly applied to any prime-regular number combination to find the divisibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked about two different kinds of divisibility tests.

The tests for divisibility by $2$ and $5$ work so nicely because we write our numbers in base $10$ and those are the prime factors of $10$. If we wrote using a different base $b$ we could test for divisibility by a prime factor of $b$ by checking just the last (units) digit.

In base $10$ there are digit tests for other numbers too. You show that you know that to test for divisibility by $3$ or $9$ you use the sum of the digits. For $11$ you look at the alternating sum and difference of the digits. For $4$ you look at the last two digits. There's a test for $7$ too, but it's really ugly.

The second kind of test you're thinking about is the one you quote for $6$. If a number is divisible by each of two primes $p$ and $q$ then it will be divisible by their product $pq$. That's a fact about numbers and doesn't depend on the base you use to write them. (It can also be generalized a bit.)

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule (and other web links for "divisibility test").

Comment: As a generalization, in any base $b$ and for any prime $p | b$, you can test divisibility by $p^k$ by checking the last $k$ digits. That is why the test for 4 works.

Answer (score 0):

I know the following about the general case for base $b$;

If $p|b$, then you can check divisibility by $p^k$ by checking the last $k$ digits of the number in question.

If $b \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, then the sum of digits test applies.

If $p-1=b$, then the alternating sum of digits test works.

I am under the impression (possibly mistaken) that is is always possible to construct a digit test, however in the majority of cases it is rather absurd and not worth doing.

Comment: As a comment on the last thing I said, a digit test can always be constructed when we know the residues of $b^n \pmod{p}$. More times than not creating such a test would yield something very ugly, but sometimes it works well - for the case $b,p = 10,3$, we have that $10^n \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \forall n$, which is why the sum of digits test works.

Comment: For prime $p$ and base $b$ there's always a test that works on digit blocks of size $n$ for some $n$ dividing $p-1$. When $p=7$ and $b=10$ you need blocks of length $6$, so not very useful.